# How to reference Enum inside a Java class from Clojure

Tags: enums, clojure, clojure-java-interop

How do I reference Enum constant which is enclosed inside a Java class from Clojure? I'm trying to use the field `P2PKH` from `org.bitcoinj.script.Script.ScriptType`. [See API of bitcoinj](https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.15.2/org/bitcoinj/script/Script.ScriptType.html#P2PKH).

In a [Java interop guide](https://purelyfunctional.tv/article/tricks-for-java-interop/) they say:

> You can refer to those enumerations in Clojure like this:
>
> DaysOfWeek/TUESDAY

But that doesn't work when the Enum is enclosed in a class. What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use syntax for accessing static inner classes:

`OuterClass$InnerClass/staticField`

so it should be:

`org.bitcoinj.script.Script$ScriptType/P2PKH`.